# Calculus of indications: Why does $\overline{a \; b |}$ gives us the connective for the Sheffer stroke?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I'm reading Williams "Logic and Integer Programming", here:

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

**Question:** I think I understand why $\overline{a |}$ gives the truth table given in there but why does $\overline{a \; b |}$ gives us the connective for the Sheffer stroke?